# How to get rid of weird line when using curves with Geo Nodes?

Tags: bezier-curves, artifacts, geometry-nodes

I am applying the following geometry nodes setup to a Bezier curve and getting this weird line. It seems to become less pronounced if I lower the curve P resolution, but I want to keep it high. How would it be possible to get rid of this line?

The Bezier curve has three points, and the seam seems to go away if I adjust the handles of the middle point quite dramatically, but that changes the shape significantly.

[image]

*The line I am talking about is the one going across the mesh perpendicular to the curve.*

**UPDATE**

I have found a workaround which does not quite solve the issue, but seems to improve the situation significantly - using a lower resolution curve with subdivision surface node. Still, it is a compromise.

[image]

*The shape of the mesh does not exactly match, but the curve is the same and the unwanted line is much less pronounced.*

Comment: seems to work in 3.1.  Hint: it is always helpful if you would provide blend file...

Comment: works in 3.0 too...pls provide blend file. Looks like your curve is strange...

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that blend exchange didn't accept my file. Here is a link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1un2rPTns5D-uvnn1FNV_jTVU5MyGxltj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Timaroberts I want to be able to control the shape from edit mode using the curve. Would it be possible to do that with an empty mesh?

Comment: @RolansKims see my answer, the segment node has all the controls for the handles and endpoints of the curve. Admittedly it does take a moment to get used to them as it is not very visual (no handles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems like this are usually going from bad topology.
So first of all, I turn on "wireframe" in "viewport display".

[image]

And i see that this is a crease. Faces are extremly scaled in the direction across curve. In other words there are too much cuts along curve. So the solution is to reduce number of cuts along curve. That is why you should add "Resample Curve" node, because it gives you ability to manage cuts count along curve.

[image]

And now you can add "Subdivision Surface" node.

[image]

And finally you can take a look at the ideal shape of the fixed curve. :)

[image]

Comment: Great! Reading about a crease for a moment I thought that there's a gradual, consistent change of normals along the surface except there's some tight (holding) loops at the height of the control point. However, the density is somewhat consistent: https://i.imgur.com/ENJWYAo.gif yes, the density does change at the spot, but I would expect subdividing the top (less dance) part wouldn't fix it, it's the abrupt change of the angle that causes the problem. But then I added the *Resample Curve* and it immediately fixes the outside of the bend... https://i.imgur.com/vejw6RJ.gif

Comment: ...Now the problem looks more like what I'd expect: the larger part of the curve "eats" the smaller part due to a too tight bend. And it seems your solution, s.s. is indeed the most reasonable way to smooth that out. Moving the s.s. to the modifier stack allows to add *Split Edges* in between and decrease the s.s. level to 1 or 2: https://i.imgur.com/UymMPjY.png https://i.imgur.com/30jDbPH.gif

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady It is also possible to manage resamle dencity along curve. And probably in will be very helpfull in some cases when we need ideal topology. Please, take a look at my question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250612/geometry-nodes-how-to-change-points-density-along-curves-if-curves-are-instan . I think that for single curve Hans Goudey answer will be best.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I love your soluthion for curve cap. Probably i can make ideal topology even on the caps of the curve, and remove any subdivision smoothing artifacts from there, using only geometry nodes. But I think it should be new 
question . Also it would be very intresting to attach halph of uv sphere instead of simple curve cap.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention your end goal, but for this object at least, it seems it might be simpler to just create it with a GN setup in an empty mesh like below:

[image]

This produces a curve as pictured here with no artifacts:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try this approach. Would it be possible to have more than two control points and two handles per point instead of one using this method?

Comment: @RolansKims no, I don't think so.

Comment: @RolansKims geometry nodes gives you ability to create curve with any count of control points. And each control point will have two handles. Also geometry nodes give you ability to select and manage any point and any handle. Just take a look how i manage points and handles in my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249028/is-there-any-way-to-produce-random-transformation-bezier-curve-geometry-nodes/251583#251583

Answer (score 1):

select your curve, tab -> edit mode, select one vertex and scale it up -> solved

[image]

Comment: This works, but also changes the shape of the curve significantly. Is there any way to keep the shape of the curve close to the original while still getting rid of the line and keeping the curve P resolution?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes it does, i now. Unfortunately i don't know another solution.